# Laravel Authorizing Channels with custom guard

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

How i can authorize on channels as described there

[Defining Authorization Callbacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#defining-authorization-callbacks)

```
Broadcast::channel('order.{order}', function ($user, Order $order) {
    return $user->id === $order->user_id;
});
```

with custom guard?

If i use standard auth it work normally. If i login with custom guard it don't work absolutely.

I have 403 exception here (/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/Broadcaster.php)

```
/**
 * Authenticate the incoming request for a given channel.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string  $channel
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function verifyUserCanAccessChannel($request, $channel)
{
    foreach ($this->channels as $pattern => $callback) {
        if (! Str::is($pattern, $channel)) {
            continue;
        }

        $parameters = $this->extractAuthParameters($pattern, $channel);

        if ($result = $callback($request->user(), ...$parameters)) {
            return $this->validAuthenticationResponse($request, $result);
        }
    }

    throw new HttpException(403);
}
```

Because i have null in $request->user() with custom guard (

oK, i change it to $request->user('my_custom_guard')

and now it work. But it don't work with standard users.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the error you are getting here?

Comment: please provide fair details, code related with your issue

Comment: I have 'Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403' in laravel echo server error log. And exception without message in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/Broadcaster.php line 53